# Hausman-Test with glmer

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

at the moment I have to decide between a random-effect or a fixed-effect model with a binary dependent variable y. The best way to decide between these two models is normally to use the Hausman-Test (e.g. Green 2012). My problem is first, that I don't understand the exact model specifications and second, that I'm not sure if my approach is the right one.

My models look like this: Mixed Effects Model

```
ModelME<-glmer(populist ~ wkb+ married + age + I(age^2)+(1|pid),
              data = phi4,
              family = binomial(link = 'logit'),nAGQ=10)
```

and Fixed Effects Model

```
 ModelFE<-glm(populist ~ wkb+ married + age + I(age^2)+pid,
                data = phi4,
                family = binomial(link = 'logit'))
```

and to specify the Hausman-Test I use the code of another question here on stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23630214/hausmans-specification-test-for-glmer-from-lme4).

and then use the test:

```
phtest_glmer(logitD,logitFE)
```

with this result:

```
Hausman Test

data:  phi4
chisq = 3234.6, df = 5, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```

So my questions are: 
1. Describes (1|pid) the random effect?
2. Is ModelFE even a Fixed Effects Model? 
3. Is the result of the Hausman-Test in any way correct? 
4. Should I use another package to use the Hausman-Test?

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you. And please tell me, if you need more information!

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess `pid` is a patient or person identifier, so you have repeated measures from the same persons. If so, I would include *time* as well in your model, e.g.

```
glmer(populist ~ wkb + married + age + I(age^2) + time + (1 + time | pid)
```

Regarding your questions:

1. yes, `(1 | pid)` describes the random part of your model. You have a varying intercept (`1`) for each `pid`, i.e. you assume that your outcome has a different average value for each `pid`. In repeated measurement / longitudinal design, you may also assume that your outcome varies stronger/weaker for different `pid`, i.e. you have *random slopes* as well. That's why I would add *time* as well.
2. A "Fixed Effects" Model would require some data preparation, e.g. demeaning and removing the intercept. So from a first quick glance, I would say it does not perfectly describe a FE model.
3. & 4. I personally would not use the Hausman-test, nor a fixed effects regression at all. There a some good publications showing that the mixed model is in general better than any fixed effects model. You can find examples that summarizes these discussion a bit [here](https://strengejacke.github.io/mixed-models-snippets/random-effects-within-between-effects-model.html) and also some information about the issue of correlated group factors and fixed effects [here](https://easystats.github.io/parameters/reference/demean.html), and how to address these issues using mixed models.

Summary: mixed models can model both between- and within-effects (while FE can only model within-effects), FE models lack information of variation in the group-effects or between-subject effects, FE regression cannot include random slopes (thus neglecting “cross-cluster differences in the effects of lower-level controls (which) reduces the precision of estimated context effects, resulting in unnecessarily wide confidence intervals and low statistical power” (*Heisig et al. 2017*).

Here are some of the references that I suggest reading:

- Bafumi J, Gelman A. 2006. Fitting Multilevel Models When Predictors and Group Effects Correlate. In. Philadelphia, PA: Annual meeting of the American Political Science Association.
- Bell A, Fairbrother M, Jones K. 2018. Fixed and Random Effects Models: Making an Informed Choice. Quality & Quantity.
- Bell A, Jones K. 2015. Explaining Fixed Effects: Random Effects Modeling of Time-Series Cross-Sectional and Panel Data. Political Science Research and Methods, 3(1), 133–153.
- Gelman, Andrew, and Jennifer Hill. 2007. Data Analysis Using Regression and Multilevel/Hierarchical Models. Analytical Methods for Social Research. Cambridge ; New York: Cambridge University Press (in particular chapter 12.6)
- Heisig JP, Schaeffer M, Giesecke J. 2017. The Costs of Simplicity: Why Multilevel Models May Benefit from Accounting for Cross-Cluster Differences in the Effects of Controls. American Sociological Review 82 (4): 796–827.